# Moving embedded chart to a new chart sheet and renaming sheet

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I'm trying to loop through charts in a specific worksheet and moving them to a new chart sheet at the end of all the sheets. Also, I want to rename the chart sheet and change the tab colour.

Here is my code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, co As ChartObject, c As Chart

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("nameofSheet")
ws.Activate

For Each co In ws.ChartObjects
    co.Activate
    Set c = co.Chart

    'move chart to new sheet at the end
    c.Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)

    'rename chart sheet
    c.Name = "newChartSheetName"

    'change colour
    c.Tab.Color = RGB(1,1,1)
Next co
```

However, it doesn't work and throws the error: `Run-time error '1004': Method 'Move' of object '_Chart' failed`

I've searched extensively but couldn't find any answer to this problem. I've tried using co (`ChartObject`) directly, but that didn't work. I've read that you should `.Activate` an object before doing something to it, but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an embedded chart, you need to convert to a chart sheet first:

```
Set c = c.Location(where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, "newChartSheetName")
c.Move After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I put `Set c = c.Location(where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet, Name:=chartSheetName)` right after `Set c = co.Chart` and removed `c.Name = chartSheetName` since it's taken care of in `move`. However, it only works for the first chart, then throws a `Method 'Location' of object '_Chart' failed` error. If I delete the new chart sheet and re-run the code, it again only works for the first chart.

Comment: You are using a different name for each chart sheet?

Comment: Ahhh! It was supposed to generate a correct, different name for each chart (obviously I don't literally use `"newChartSheetName"`), but it indeed doesn't work. I'll debug that. Thanks a lot!